# Message Status Callback From A Bot Framework Twilio Channel

Tags: twilio, botframework

I have a Microsoft Bot Framework bot running using a Twilio channel to send SMS messages.  Everything is working, however I need to see if I can find a way to determine the SMS message delivery status.  Because the Bot Framework via the Twilio channel is handling all the messaging I can't just set a web hook URL in the Twilio request normally since the Bot Framework handles all that.

Hoping I could override this - I tried to put the URL in the TwiML app's Status Callback URL but it's not firing.

Does anyone know if there is a way to somehow override the Status callback URL in Twilio or get an event back to my Bot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the TwiML App, you can add a status callback URL. Then in your bot you can add a new endpoint to receive the status updates. The incoming requests should have the message ids that you can use to map to your conversations.

[image]

**Bot Framework SDK v4 (Node)**

```
server.post('/MessageStatus', (req, res) => {
  const messageSid = req.body.MessageSid;
  const messageStatus = req.body.MessageStatus;

  console.log(`SID: ${ messageSid }, Status: ${ messageStatus }`);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

For more details, take a look at the Twillio [Staus Callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-node-js) documentation.

Comment: @trurnford are you sure this works? Ryan, where you able to get it working?
I have configured the status callback url in the phone # I'm using but I don't get any callbacks at all.